# WVD App attach launching windows file explorer

Tags: troubleshooting

I'm trying to virtualize some apps and test the app attach feature with MSIX packages. I've followed all the steps, and expanded the MSIX into a VHD. I've uploaded the VHD and placed it in a hostpool / app group. It launches. However, it launches file explorer, and not the app itself:

WVD and APP - App Attach launch:

[image: WVD and APP - App Attach launch]

Is there something I'm missing? I've read the documentation several times, and re-traced my steps countless times. I'm sure I'm missing something, but just not sure what at the moment.

Thank you in advance.

-Richard F.

Comment: Having the same issue here, did you find a solution?